# How to check if nested related data is out of date in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is a example from ChatGPT.

> To check if nested related data is out of date in a Rails form, you can compare the date value of the nested data with the current date in your controller or view. You can then display an appropriate message or take further action based on the result of the comparison.

Here's an example of how you can accomplish this:

1. Assuming you have a Post model that has many Comments:

```rb
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

2. In your controller action, retrieve the post and its associated comments:

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments
end
```

3. In your view, iterate over the comments and compare the expiry date with the current date. You can then display a message or apply conditional formatting based on the result:

```rb
<!-- app/views/posts/edit.html.erb -->
<%= form_for @post do |form| %>
  <!-- Post fields... -->

  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <% if comment.expiry_date < Date.current %>
      <p class="expired-comment">
        This comment is expired!
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <%= form.fields_for :comments, comment do |comment_form| %>
        <!-- Comment fields... -->
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

> In the above example, we iterate over each comment associated with the post. If a comment's expiry date is earlier than the current date, we display an "expired" message. Otherwise, we render the comment fields within the nested form.

> You can customize the presentation and behavior based on your specific requirements. For example, you could disable editing or apply a different style to expired comments.

> Remember to adjust the code according to your specific model and attribute names.

> This approach allows you to visually indicate or handle expired comments within your form based on the expiry date comparison.

---

But my project is opposite!

```rb
rails g scaffold user name

rails g scaffold certificate name exam_date:date

rails g scaffold enrole user:references certificate:references money:integer
```

```rb
#config/routes.rb

resources :certificates do
  resources :enroles
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enroles, dependent: :destroy
end

class Certificate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enroles, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enroles
end

class Enrole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :certificate, optional: true
end
```

I have 2 questions.

1. I want to show warning when enrole form commited with exam_date < Time.now (expired), How can I do?
   Otherwise, if enrole form can be disabled is perfect!
2. I want to disallow any user enrole twice! I try to do that:

```rb
class Enrole < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :certificate_id, scope: :user_id
```

It's work! but maybe the cerfificate have many times, I want to bind exam_date field with this rule, I try to do that:

```rb
class Enrole < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :certificate_id, scope: [:user_id, :exam_date]
```

But failed, Please help me, thanks ^_^